# Google Apps Script Convert Positive into Negative Value When Pasting In Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I make a positive value be converted automatically into negative without adding formula to a cell when someone pastes/or added a value to a cell.

In this example I want that 5 2 and 3 be a negative value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using the simple trigger of `onEdit` as follows?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a positive value to a cell. By this, the positive value is converted to the negative value.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const value = e.range.getValue();
  if (!isNaN(value) && value > 0) {
    e.range.setValue(-value);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to limit the sheet and the range, please tell me.
- If you want to convert all cell values in a sheet by a script, how about the following script? When this script is run, the positive values in a sheet are converted to negative values.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
      const range = sheet.getDataRange();
      const values = range.getValues().map(r => r.map(c => !isNaN(c) && c > 0 ? -c : c));
      range.setValues(values);
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

### Added 1:

From your following additional request,

> Is it possible to apply it with certain range only. Like to cell C45:AK76 and C84:AK115?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const ranges = ["C45:AK76", "C84:AK115"]; // These ranges are from your reply.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const value = range.getValue();
  const check = sheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().some(r => {
    const startRow = r.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startCol = r.getColumn();
    const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    return range.rowStart >= startRow && range.rowEnd <= endRow && range.columnStart >= startCol && range.columnEnd <= endCol;
  });
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || !check || isNaN(value) || value < 0) return;
  range.setValue(-value);
}
```

- In this sample, the script is run when the cells "C45:AK76", "C84:AK115" are edited.

### Added 2:

From your following additional request,

> Im wondering if I can apply this to two other sheets with the same cell range?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const ranges = ["C45:AK76", "C84:AK115"]; // These ranges are from your reply.
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set your sheet names.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const value = range.getValue();
  const check = sheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().some(r => {
    const startRow = r.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startCol = r.getColumn();
    const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    return range.rowStart >= startRow && range.rowEnd <= endRow && range.columnStart >= startCol && range.columnEnd <= endCol;
  });
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || !check || isNaN(value) || value < 0) return;
  range.setValue(-value);
}
```

### Added 3:

From your following additional request,

> If I paste for example these 3 different values into the cell., example the number 4 5 and 6. Instead of just having -4,-5, and -6. The result I'm getting is -4,-4 and -4.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const ranges = ["C45:AK76", "C84:AK115"]; // These ranges are from your reply.
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set your sheet names.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const values = range.getValues();
  const check = sheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().some(r => {
    const startRow = r.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startCol = r.getColumn();
    const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    return range.rowStart >= startRow && range.rowEnd <= endRow && range.columnStart >= startCol && range.columnEnd <= endCol;
  });
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || !check) return;
  range.setValues(values.map(r => r.map(c => (!isNaN(c) && c > 0) ? -c : c)));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thank you for your help. Is it possible to apply it with certain range only. Like to cell C45:AK76 and C84:AK115?

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. From your additional request, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: apologies for late response. This works perfectly well. Thank you so much. You're awesome. Im wondering if I can apply this to two other sheets with the same cell range?

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your additional request, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. I tried this one however after pasting the value, it changes the values with the first value of pasted data. Examples, i tried pasting, 1 2 3, then it came out as -1,-1,-1

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. About your reply, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In my answer, there are 3 sample scripts from your initial question, 2nd question, and 3rd question. So, I cannot understand `this` of `I tried this`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, basically the issue was. If I paste for example these 3 different values into the cell., example the number 4 5 and 6. Instead of just having -4,-5, and -6. The result I'm getting is -4,-4 and -4.

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. From your additional request, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. From `It worked! Thank you kindly Sir.`, I understood that your issues were resolved. I'm glad about it.